# Unable to run play application using guice for dependency injcetion

Tags: scala, dependency-injection, playframework, guice

I am trying to run a play application where I have used guice for dependency injection.

My controller is as follows

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext
import javax.inject.Inject
import play.api.libs.json.Json
import play.api.mvc._

class MyControllers @Inject()(
    service: MyService,
    cc: MessagesControllerComponents)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext)
    extends MessagesAbstractController(cc) {

  def getAll(id: Int): Action[AnyContent] = Action.async { implicit request =>
      // code to fetch from service and return result
  }
```

Similarly in my service I have dependency injected the DAO as

```
class MyService @Inject()(dao: MyDAO)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext) {

// call to DB

}
```

My build.sbt file looks something like this

```
name := """service-application"""

version := "2.6.x"

scalaVersion := "2.12.7"

crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.11.12", "2.12.4")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  guice,
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick" % "3.0.3",
  "com.typesafe.play" %% "play-slick-evolutions" % "3.0.3",
  "org.mockito" % "mockito-all" % "1.10.19" % Test,
  "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.197",
  "org.scalactic" %% "scalactic" % "3.0.5",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "3.0.5" % "test",
  "org.scalatestplus.play" %% "scalatestplus-play" % "3.1.2" % Test,
  "net.codingwell" %% "scala-guice" % "4.1.0",
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-codegen" % "3.2.1",
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick-testkit" % "3.2.3" % Test,
  specs2 % Test
)

addSbtPlugin("com.geirsson" % "sbt-scalafmt" % "1.5.1")

routesGenerator := InjectedRoutesGenerator
```

However, now when I am trying to run the play application via the sbt shell using command

```
run
```

I get the error as

```
[IJ]sbt:service-application> run
[error] java.lang.RuntimeException: No main class detected.
[error]     at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
[error] (Compile / bgRun) No main class detected.
[error] Total time: 1 s
```

Could you please let me know what I am missing here ? Is it some kind of configuration that I am missing in the conf file ?

Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: Everything looks fine to me, but still I was getting this error and hence I turned up to the Stackoverflow community to help me out

Comment: Are you using the Play SBT plugin in `project/plugins.sbt`? If so I think you need to enable the plugin: `enablePlugins(playScala)` in your `build.sbt`. If not, maybe try the plugin.

Comment: @Lasf tried that too. Didn't get it running :(

Comment: Okay. For what it's worth I can tell from your sbt prompt `sbt:service-application>` that it's not picking up the sbt plugin. Were the plugin properly enabled, you would see a colorful `[service-application] $` prompt. If the plugin is not enabled, then you won't have a (hidden) `main` class as an application starting point. So I would focus my debugging efforts there.

Comment: ok. @Lasf let me try once more

Comment: See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/BuildOverview (adjust to your Play version)